# Delete a thread sms in Android with KITKAT version

Tags: java, android, sms

I created an apk to send multiple SMS to each customers of my corporation in a loop:

```
        android.telephony.SmsManager smsManager = android.telephony.SmsManager.getDefault();

        for (int i = 0; i < sms.size(); i++) {
            String text = sms.get(i).get("texte").toString();
            String num = sms.get(i).get("num").toString();
            Log.v("testMortel", text);
            Log.v("testMortelNum", num);
            try {

                smsManager.sendTextMessage(num, null, text, null, null);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("PhoneNo", "fail");
            }

            Intent a = new Intent(SendSms_Activity.this, Campagnes_Activity.class);
            startActivity(a);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Campagne SMS envoyée", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // affichage du toast envoyé

             Cursor c = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), null, null, null,null);
            try {
                    c.moveToPosition(0);
                     int Id = c.getInt(0);
                    // String uri = "content://sms/conversations/" + threadId;
                     String strUriAll = "content://sms/" + Id; //first thread sms
                     Log.d("URI is ", strUriAll);
                     getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(strUriAll), null, null);                       

                }catch(Exception e){
                     Log.e(this.toString(),"Error deleting sms",e);
                }finally {
                  c.close();
                }
}
```

So, I have my code above and deleting the first top thread works on phone under kitkat version.
But with a smartphone with kitkat it doesn't work anymore..

**So, How can we delete the first top thread in a default SMS application with a phone working on kitkat ?**

PS : I heard about kitkat version which I have to get the default SMS application before but don't really know how it works..

Comment: Have you gone through [this page](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html?m=1) to make sure your app is able to be the default SMS app? It takes a bit of work, as your app is then responsible for several things it may not have implemented before.

Comment: My app only send SMS, it doesn't receive any SMS. My app works under  the kitkat version, it send for example a simple SMS to 100 different number and it appears on my native SMS app and with the code to delete the first top sms of my native sms application I managed to erase the "history"of that send.. But now in kitkat version it doesn't work..

Comment: Did you read the links in my post that you commented on to bring me here? To delete from the Content Provider, you need write access to it. You cannot acquire write access to that Provider in KitKat without being the default SMS app. Any app can still send SMS messages the old way, and the system will take care of those writes for you. But, to directly delete anything, your app _must be_ the default.

Comment: Ok my code seems to work, But i have one more question ( maybe i should create a new question ) : is it possible to avoid the "get sms application default pop-up" to show ? I mean this 
`final String myPackageName = getPackageName();
  if (!Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this).equals(myPackageName)) {
   // if App is not default.

   Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
   intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, myPackageName);
   startActivity(intent);`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Once the user selects your app as default, it shouldn't pop up anymore.